# Git: local branchs tracks other local branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I know that local branches can track remote branches, but there is also the possibility that a local branch tracks another local branch. What is a use-case for this?

Answer (score 1):

Real-world use:

I have an upstream repository, and a local branch tracking that remote. I start working on a major "feature" which will require a mess of changes to implement, but I don't yet want to expose the work upstream (potentially, ever).

So I create a local branch tracking my tracking branch. Now I have `origin/master`, `master` tracking that, and `feature` tracking `master`. So whenever `origin/master` is updated, I can keep `origin/master` up to date, and then apply my feature-specific changes on top of any uncommitted changes in the local `master`.

The reason why `feature` isn't directly tracking `origin/master` is that it may depend on work in the local `master` branch which isn't yet committed but isn't major enough to warrant its own feature branch.

This could also be useful for multiple independent features - `basefeature` tracks `master`,  and `subfeature` tracks `basefeature`.

Comment: How do you actually *use* the tracking (aka "move" `feature` or `master`)? I guess, pull or push won't work.

Comment: @MikeL. When `master` has a new change `feature` should incorporate, you `git rebase master` or `git merge master` from `feature`. When you want to move the changes "back" (called "reintegration"), you `git merge feature` into the `master` branch.

Comment: I'm using independent feature branches and rebase them onto `master` regularly using a famous GUI client ;). What is the benefit now with the configured tracking? Shorter commands?

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to have push/pull for local branches. Just rebase your local feature branches every time on top of you new master HEAD.

Comment: @MikeL. `git status` shows you how far ahead/behind you are, for one :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one I actually needed:

We're working on a big project, with multiple teams working on multiple features. So, we have `master`, and `feature-1`, `feature-2`, etc. branches.

Let's say I'm currently working on `feature-1`. Working on a feature branch doesn't mean actually committing to that branch, rather branching off of that branch. Say I have been working on this feature for a couple months. I use `git diff HEAD feature-1` a lot and other commands that involve the feature branch I'm working on.

Two months later, I started working on another branch. Now I have to be careful when running commands to use the new feature branch name `feature-3`, so to speak.

Wouldn't it be easier to have a branch `active-feature` that points to the feature branch I'm currently working on? I mean, I'm working on `feature-1` and I can easily run then `git diff HEAD active-feature`. When I'm working on another feature, I need only to set `active-feature` to the new feature branch, and I can easily from thereafter use `active-feature` which boils down to the new feature branch.