# Git Local Branch Tracking Another Local Branch

Tags: git, branch

I have been searching for a way to make a local branch track another local branch in git. I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Why do I need this you might ask. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63507167/1051589)'s my use case.

So, is there a way to make a local branch track another local branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply :

```
git branch -u otherbranch
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed trying this out before actually posting a question. My bad.